# Foursquare: is it "message" or "errorMessage"?

Tags: php, api, foursquare

I try to program a PHP client for Foursquare API, but I have problems to unterstand https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/responses

> The meta section may also contain a message

but:

> the server may include an errorMessage

So what is correct? `message` or `errorMessage`?

Answer (score 1):

They're documented under different headings.
Normal **responses** may contain a `message`.
**Errors** may (also?) contain an `errorMessage`.

Answer (score 0):

From reading that page it looks like "message" is a string intended to be used for debugging purposes by the developer. "errorMessage" is a string containing information to be displayed to the user about what went wrong.

"message" - debug statement
"errorMessage" - user friendly error message.